# Update automatically

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

```
-- Rough Work for MMID Updation Automatically

CREATE TABLE main
(
  sno serial NOT NULL,
  mid integer,
  mmid integer,
  venue text,
  CONSTRAINT pk_sno PRIMARY KEY (sno)
);


INSERT INTO main(mid, mmid, venue) VALUES(1, 1, 'Ramesh Gardens');
INSERT INTO main(mid, mmid, venue) VALUES(1, 2, 'Suresh Gardens');
INSERT INTO main(mid, mmid, venue) VALUES(1, 3, 'Kamesh Gardens');
INSERT INTO main(mid, mmid, venue) VALUES(2, 1, 'Rajesh Gardens');
INSERT INTO main(mid, mmid, venue) VALUES(2, 2, 'Rajesh Gardens');
```

I need to update column `mmid` value to `1` whenever a new record is inserted basing on the change of `mid` value

Here `mid` represents `Meeting_ID` and `mmid` represents `SubMeeting_ID`. I have tried Like this.

```
SELECT * FROM main;

INSERT INTO main(mid, mmid, venue) VALUES((SELECT MAX(mid) FROM main)+1,(SELECT MAX(mmid) FROM main WHERE mid=(SELECT MAX(mid) FROM main))+1,'Rajesh Gardens');

SELECT * FROM main;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bdf53/2)

Answer (score 1):

Keeping values like this in the table is hard and error prone, are you sure you don't want to just calculate it inline in some view like this:

```
select
    sno, mid, venue, row_number() over(partition by mid order by sno) as mmid
from main
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bdf53/3)

Comment: ***Here mid represents Meeting_ID and mmid represents SubMeeting_ID***  It is not just a row count.

Comment: then I don't understood your task, could you provide sample input and output with explanation?

Comment: Actually its a meeting manager. While working on a project we can have many meetings having same goal. When a meeting is created, we will have a meeting id (say 1) and we can have any no of submeetings in that meeeting so they are represented as 1,2,3.... I need to update mmid as 1 whenever mid is changed (i.e., when a new meeeting is created).